# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, javascript-objects

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
```

Relevant code (used in a React project):

```
const transformedIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredients)
  .map(igKey => {
    return [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i) => {
      return <BurgerIngredient key={ igKey + i } type={ igKey } />;
    });
  });
```

Comment: You props.ingredients seems to be null you can default that `props.ingredients || {}`

Answer (score 2):

That error is coming from `Object.keys(props.ingredients)`, as `props.ingredients` is `undefined` or `null`, as stated on the error message:

```js
let ingredients; // No initialization, so this is undefined.

const transformedIngredients = Object.keys(ingredients).map(i => i);
```

You should either add some logic to make sure this code is only executed once or if `prop.ingredients` has a value or you could just use the [OR (`||`) operator's short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#Short-circuit_evaluation) to provide a fallback:

```js
let ingredients;

const transformedIngredients = Object.keys(ingredients || {}).map(i => i);
```